# Git: How do I retrieve my branch's files back from Github?

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project, repeatedly pushing changes up to GitHub. A huge error occurred meaning I had to revert my branch back to master, losing all my work locally.

My changes are still on GitHub, but I am not sure how to retrieve them.

I've tried `git checkout .` with no results and many of the other results I've Googled mention only retrieving changes from master, which I don't want to do.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: git checkout <yourbranch>; git pull?

Comment: _"I had to revert my branch back to master,"_ - what exactly did you do to revert back to master?

Comment: @1615903 I don't know, support did it

Answer (score 0):

Verify your remote as `git remote`  If you have remote then go to branch which you want to retrieve view your branches as `git branch` if you have not that branch then create as  `git checkout -b branchname` and pull it as

> `git pull remotename branchname`

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I know what 'remotename' is?

Comment: i mentioned above it can be checked if you execute command  `git remote`